# Initializing floats with integer immediate values & warnings

Tags: c++, int, type-conversion, floating-point-precision

In my code, I initialize a lot of floats with 0, 1 and 2 values (or other small ints). While GCC produces no warnings for this, MSVC does. So I replaced all 0's by `0.f`, 1's by `1.f`, etc... Also initializing a float with 0.5 issues a warning, and I replaced it by 0.5f.

While I fully understand that doing `float f=someInt` or `float f=someDouble` should produce a warning as in some cases precision is lost, the compiler should be smart enough to know that 0, 1, 2 and 0.5 are exact float values. And my code is much less readable like that...

Is MSVC not using some standard? Should I let him complain or make my code less readable?

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine the warning in question is `conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data`?

Comment: I don't get exactly what's your question... you already understood the important points, the rest is mostly a matter of style, there's no right answer. Personally, I just got the habit of always specifying the correct type for floating point literals everywhere; I wouldn't say it makes the code less readable, and immediately conveys the type of the literals we are talking about (and, when performing computations or calling functions, can avoid surprises).

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the beholder, but I see your point. I too would probably find this slightly annoying.

Comment: `int` is an `int`, no matter if it's `0` or `9011`. I don't think it's reasonable for a compiler to produce the warning for one value and not to produce it for another.

Comment: Turn off stupid warnings.

Comment: There's no standard for warnings, only for some (but not all) errors. It's up to the compiler whether or not to whinge about possible loss of precision, and how smart to be about it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The problem is that the resolution isn't good enough. You can't turn off the stupid warning for known-good compile-time constants and keep the useful warning for known-bad and runtime values. Quality Of Implementation, basically.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - formally, the **only** thing that requires a compiler to refuse to compile code is a `#error` directive. Other than that, the requirement is that the compiler issue a diagnostic; having done that, it's free to continue to compile the code, with, of course, implementation-specific semantics. The tradition is that compilers give error messages when they're not going to compile, and warning messages when they are. But that distinction is not part of the language definition.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Indeed; there are plently of things it's required to diagnose (which I'll loosely call "errors"), even if it's not required to refuse to accept them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - if you think that the benefits of that warning are worth the costs, by all means keep it. I turn it off.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Eh? When did I say anything like that? I just said that there's no standard for warnings, without offering any opinion about which to enable.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - sorry, wrong attribution. That was meant for MSalters.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] the compiler should be smart enough to know that 0, 1, 2 and 0.5 are exact float values.

That may be the case, but do you really want the compiler to use that knowledge to suppress warnings? Consider the following code snippet:

```
double fun()
{
    float calculated = UNIVERSAL_BASE_VALUE;
    // Do some calculations.
    return calculated;
}
```

Suppose `UNIVERSAL_BASE_VALUE` is a constant defined in a header file somewhere. And maybe its type is `double`. But maybe its value is 0.5, which is an exact `float` value, so the compiler could use its knowledge to suppress a warning in this case.

Now fast-forward a few years. This fun function has not been touched in the interim, but businesses change, and someone wants to try changing the definition of `UNIVERSAL_BASE_VALUE` from 0.5 to 0.51. Suddenly there is a compiler warning for that function that has been stable for years. Why is this? There was no logical change, just a small data change. Yet that data change gave `UNIVERSAL_BASE_VALUE` a value that cannot be exactly represented in a `float`. The compiler no longer stays quiet about the conversion. After investigating, it is discovered that the type of `calculated` had been wrong for all those years, causing `fun()` to return imprecise results. Time to blame the compiler for being too smart? :)

*Note that you get a similar situation if you replace `UNIVERSAL_BASE_VALUE` with a literal `0.5`. It just makes the ending less dramatic while the overall point still holds: being smart could let a bug slip through.*

---

Compiler warnings are intended to alert you to potential bugs. This is not an exact science, as programmer intent can be hard to deduce, especially when coding styles vary. There is no comprehensive standard covering all warnings a compiler may choose to emit. When false positives arise, it is up to the programmers to make a judgement call for their specific case. I can think of four basic approaches to choose between.

1. Turn off a warning (because it doesn't really help your code).
2. Accept that warnings are generated when compiling (not a good choice).
3. Change the coding style to accommodate the warnings (time consuming).
4. Whine to the compiler's developers (err… ask nicely for changes; don't whine).

**Do *not* choose option 2.** This would mean accumulating warnings that humans learn to ignore. Once you accumulate enough "accepted" warnings, it becomes difficult to spot other warnings that pop up. They get lost in the crowd, hence fail to achieve their intended purpose.

Note that compilers tend to support suppressing certain warnings for just certain lines of certain files. This gives a compromise between options 1 and 2 that might be acceptable.

In your case, you would need to evaluate this warning for your code base. If it provides value by spotting bugs, you should go with what you call "less readable". (It's not really less readable, but it does take time to get used to it.) If the warning does not provide enough value to warrant a style change, turn the warning off.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write the code to be warning free.

If that makes it hard to read, this points to a problem somewhere else, like an unhealthy mix of float and double, which easily leads to a loss of precision or arithmetically unstable results.

Once upon a time I had a program which crashed with a coredump when it finished. The compiler gave some warnings because I had an unhealthy mix of char* and char[].

When I fixed these warnings, the program was suddenly stable (no more memory corruption).

So, turn on all warnings and change the code to compile warning free.

The compiler just wants to help you!